# Is it possible to return actual code in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a class that needs to initialize a logger.

I want to be able to select the 'logging level' of the logger (info,warning,error).

I thought of using parameters like this:

```
class classA:

    def __init__(self, logLevel = 'info'):

        #stuff
        #initialize logger
        self.logger.setLevel(logLevel)
```

But I am pretty sure that doesn't work.

So I thought of replacing `logLevel` with `getLogLevel(logLevel)`. `getLogLevel` would look like this:

```
def getLogLevel(logLevel):
    if logLevel == 'info':
        return 'logging.INFO'
    elif .......
```

But a problem here arises. I am pretty sure I cannot return 'code' like this.

Is there a way to make this cleaner without cluttering the `__init__` method?
(Btw, I know you could probably use a method that handles the logger with if statements based on `logLevel`, but I'd like to know if there are multiple ways to do this).

Comment: It certainly is possible to return a string of python code and then `eval` it...but you most certainly do NOT want to do that. Just use a dict: `lvls = {"info": logging.INFO...}` and then `self.logger.setLevel(lvls.get(logLevel))`

Comment: why does `self.logger.setLevel(logLevel)` not work ?

Comment: You can't return `'logging.INFO'`, a string, and expect it to work, but you can return `logging.INFO` which will work. Just for record, you can return "code", that is, a function, in Python just fine.

Comment: @JaredSmith that works wonderfully and made me learn something new. Thanks!

Comment: So, Python provides a lot of metaprogramming abilities. You can `compile` strings into code objects, execute those code objects, and do all sorts of things. But that is definitely not what you want to do here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using strings, where the logging enums would be more appropriate.

for example

```
class classA:

    def __init__(self, logLevel = logging.INFO):

        #stuff
        #initialize logger
        self.logger.setLevel(logLevel)
```

Or if you want to keep it as a string (you dont) and use `getLogLevel()` change it as follows:

```
def getLogLevel(logLevel):
    if logLevel == 'info':
        return logging.INFO
    elif .......
```

Comment: This works, although I prefer using dicts as they are new for me. Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

As of Python 3.2+, loggers from the stdlib `logging` module accept string representations of log levels. They just need to be upper case.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, log_level='info'):
        ...
        self.logger.setLevel(log_level.upper())
```

These loggers store their levels as ints, but you can easily get back the string representation.

```
logging.getLevelName(logger.level)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `getattr` you can get the object from the `logging` module. Try this:

```
class classA:

def __init__(self, logLevel = 'info'):

    #initialize logger
    self.logger.setLevel(getattr(self.logger, logLevel.upper()))
```

Every log level has a numeric value:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.INFO
20
>>> logging.ERROR
40
```

Using `getattr` you can pass a string and an object to get the attribute's value:

```
>>> getattr(logging, 'INFO')
20
>>> getattr(logging, 'ERROR')
40
```

Note the strings needs to be in uppercase.

This code seems little complex, since we have chained function calls.
Some might find this code cleaner:

```
class classA:

    def __init__(self, logLevel = 'info'):

        #initialize logger
        self.set_loglvl(logLevel)

    def set_loglvl(self, lvl):
        l = getattr(self.logger, lvl)
        self.logger.setLevel(self.loglvl(logLevel))
```